# Align divs with text next to icon

Tags: html, css, twig

I am creating a Bootstrap popover to show some information. There will be one or more pieces, each containing a icon and some text. 
I am also using twig for this if that changes anything.

HTML

```
<span class="fa fa-user instructor-contact-info-header"></span>    
<div class="contact-info-container">
<p class="instructor-contact-info-header"> 
    {{section.getInstructorNamesArray()[namesArrayIndex]}}
</p>                                        
<p class="instructor-contact-info-data">Put other stuff here</p>
```

CSS I have

```
.instructor-contact-info-header {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #005993;
  margin: 0;
}
```

How it looks:

```
@ 
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
```

What I am trying to get:

```
@ text text text text text text
  text text text text text text
  text text text text text text

@ text text text text text text
  text text text text text text
  text text text text text text
```

EDIT:
After implementing the solution. Popovers with multiple people's contact info shows as follows:

```
  @ text text text text text text    @
    text text text text text text
    text text text text text text
@ text text text text text text
  text text text text text text
  text text text text text text
```

Comment: You have a `span` next to a `div`? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm not too familiar with `span`

Comment: Hang on, I'm answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `span` (inline element) next to a `div` (a block element). So the `div` is a new line. Just make the `div` inline-block as well to fix it:

```css
.instructor-contact-info-header {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #005993;
  margin: 0;
}
.contact-info-container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<span class="fa fa-user instructor-contact-info-header"></span>    
<div class="contact-info-container">
<p class="instructor-contact-info-header"> 
    {{section.getInstructorNamesArray()[namesArrayIndex]}}
</p>                                        
<p class="instructor-contact-info-data">Put other stuff here</p>
</div>
<div>
<span class="fa fa-user instructor-contact-info-header"></span>    
<div class="contact-info-container">
<p class="instructor-contact-info-header"> 
    {{section.getInstructorNamesArray()[namesArrayIndex]}}
</p>                                        
<p class="instructor-contact-info-data">Put other stuff here</p>
</div>
<div>
<span class="fa fa-user instructor-contact-info-header"></span>    
<div class="contact-info-container">
<p class="instructor-contact-info-header"> 
    {{section.getInstructorNamesArray()[namesArrayIndex]}}
</p>                                        
<p class="instructor-contact-info-data">Put other stuff here</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Just wrap the whole thing in a div so it is block level.

Comment: Thanks that works in cases there is on person's contact info to display. When there are two the second span element is aligned with the first. See edited post.

Comment: Yup got it. Thanks!